# How to get LatLng object from string?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using [the following library](https://github.com/vlafranca/ngxAutocomPlace) for use Google Places in my Angular project,

Both library and Google Places requires `location` params to be a `LatLng` object but I only have the coords as a `string`, so the question is:

How can I transform this string: '44.7179422,10.5465457' in a LatLng object to pass as parameter? (I've  tried to use just `.split(',')`)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep using the `.split()` function, but you need to also convert your strings into numbers

```
const arr = str.split(',');
this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(arr[0]), Number(arr[1]));
```

here is an [article](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-convert-a-string-to-number-in-angular-or-typescript/) about different checks that might be useful when converting.